# Changing IP address from existing Mariadb10.1 Galera Cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a multimaster cluster with MariaDB Galera working properly, it is set to perform the replica through its WAN interface. This configuration was a result of a previous migration from another datacenter, but now I need to take advantage from 10Gbps internal network which gives me the new datacenter and for this I need to reconfigure the cluster IPs. That is changing the WAN IPs to LAN IPs. 
There is a specific procedure for this? Or I should just shut down gracefully the nodes, change the IP and start again?

Answer (score 1):

The nodes are not registered by their IP addresses, but by a UUID and server ID. Just ensure that `wsrep_cluster_address` reflects the nodes properly, and do a rolling restart.